# How do you include git ignored files in VSCode quick search

Tags: visual-studio-code

Working in PHP, my vendor folder is ignored by git.

If I press Command-P, how would I include ignored files in the quick search?

Comment: please provide feedback on the answer if you found it useful. Otherwise let me know what was not useful so I can adjust

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the state of inclusion for items in quick open using the following workspace (or otherwise) setting : `search.exclude`

Per their docs:

> Configure glob patterns for excluding files and folders in fulltext searches and quick open. Inherits all glob patterns from the #files.exclude# setting

Edit: I interpreted what you were asking incompletely with my initial response, but will leave it for future question seekers and also because you can use in tandem with the following.

If you would like to make sure ignored files are present in quick open use one of the following, or both, depending on the scope of which it's ignored:

```
"search.useIgnoreFiles": false,
"search.useGlobalIgnoreFiles": false
```

Comment: Thank you! I had found this in the docs, but I must have done something wrong the first time I tried it.

Comment: It's just very hard to grasp the actual meaning of the setting; "Use ignore files" will actually exclude from search whatever is ignored... Anyhow, really helped me cause I was assuming that I'm doomed